# URL rewrite rules with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^p/timeline timeline.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^p/notifications notifications.php [NC,L]
```

I can use my url like this

```
www.mysite.com/username
or
www.mysite.com/username/photos
```

But some rules does not work. For example:

```
www.mysite.com/p/timeline
```

There is a problem with url which include **mysite.com/p/..**

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first parse the rules for `p/timeline` and `p/notification`. The ordering of your rules is also important.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^p/(notifications|timeline) $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```